# Clang/LLVM on Eclipse (Mac)

Tags: c++, llvm, eclipse-cdt, clang++

I am trying to run Eclipse with the Clang compiler without success. First I went here http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html and followed the instructions 1 through 8 successfully. I also installed the llvm toolchain via Eclipse marketplace.

What do I do next to successfully compile with Clang? From the installation I have two folders, llvm and build, where do I put them? How do I connect this to Eclipse?

I also downloaded lld in case I needed it since the llvm-ld doesn't work anymore. Below is my error message. I'll be so grateful if someone can help me figure this out! I've wasted a lot of hours on this.

```
20:09:47 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project recursion ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
clang -O0 -emit-llvm -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o recursiveprint.bc ../recursiveprint.c 
lld -v -native -o recursion recursiveprint.bc 
Cannot run program "lld": Unknown reason

Error: Program "lld" not found in PATH
PATH=[/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]


20:09:47 Build Finished (took 74ms)
```

Comment: Install "Xcode" and "Xcode command line tools" first, they come with all necessary files.

Comment: I installed both of those already. How can I save my toolchain settings (the commands) so I don't have to change the settings for every new project?

Comment: I don't know much about eclipse but it's a bit weird that eclipse's trying to use "lld" to link. Couldn't you just use Xcode?